# ¿Cómo paso el valor de un input radio a un input text con Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Soy nuevo en este tema y me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de que, al momento de seleccionar el input radio, automáticamente aparezca el valor de cada uno en un input text con Jquery, en lugar de Javascript. 
¿Es posible hacer esto? 
Este es el código proporcionado el cual está en Javascript.

```js
function capturar() {
            var resultado = "ninguno";

            var porNombre = document.getElementsByName("deacuerdo");
            for (var i = 0; i < porNombre.length; i++) {
                if (porNombre[i].checked)
                    resultado = porNombre[i].value;
            }

            document.getElementById("rInput").value = " \
            Por Nombre: "+ resultado;
        }
        
       
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

 for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
  
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
    
        if(this.checked){
  
           document.getElementById("rInput").value = this.value;
        }
     }) 
     })
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Disco duro</h1>
    <form id="form">

       <input type="radio" name="disco" value="500"/>1TB<br />
   <input type="radio" name="disco" value="900"/>2TB<br />
   <input type="radio" name="disco" value="1800"/>4TB<br />

    </form>
    
    <div id="resultado"><input id="rInput" type="text"></div>


</body>
```

Comment: Hola @Christian Parra. Puedo ayudarte, pero antes deberías leer la sección de ayuda. Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Si tienes algo de código, podemos ayudarte.  Al menos, pon el input que tienes y el select

Comment: Hola @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz muchas gracias por aclararme esto. Ya incluí el código en html y javascript. ¿Será posible hacer lo mismo pero con Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el método [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) detectarás el cambio en el input y te será fácil asociar el valor

Con los [selectores de Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) puedes acceder sin problema al valor de un radio button con la opción checked activado.

Acto seguido, y en la misma línea, puedes modificar el valor del input con el método [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/). Observa que también el mísmo método vale para obtener el valor inicialmente.

```js
$("input").change(function(){

$("#rInput").val($("input:checked").val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <h1>Disco duro</h1>
  <form id="form">

    <input type="radio" name="disco" value="500" />1TB<br />
    <input type="radio" name="disco" value="900" />2TB<br />
    <input type="radio" name="disco" value="1800" />4TB<br />

  </form>

  <div id="resultado"><input id="rInput" type="text"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Wow, me sirvió muchísimo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!